# ValueError: Cannot have number of splits n_splits=5 greater than the number of samples: n_samples=3 for knn classification

Tags: python, knn, text-classification

I'm rather new to Python so bear with me: The problem relates to spam messaging.

I keep getting the error in the title when trying `knn.fit(X_train, y_train)`.

`X_train.shape` is (3, 13239) and `len(y_train)` is 3. 3 is what I expected for `n_samples` given train/test split is 80/20

I set `n_neighbours = 1` but the error still keeps popping up. I even tried changing `n_neighbours` to `n_splits` and still doesn't work.

Below is a snippet of the code:

```
    len(sms_spam)/len(sms_spam+sms_ham)  #= 0.5, therefore balanced

    #getting feature vectors
    CountVec = CountVectorizer(lowercase=True,analyzer='word',stop_words='english') 
    feature_vectors = CountVec.fit_transform(sms_ham + sms_spam) 
    CountVec.get_feature_names_out() 

    feature_vectors.shape #(4, 13239)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feature_vectors, [0] * len(sms_ham) + [1] * len(sms_spam), random_state = 0, test_size=0.2) 


#KNN 

    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1, p=1) 

    hyperparameters = { 
    
    'n_neighbors': [1],

        'p': [2] 

    } 


    knn = GridSearchCV(knn, hyperparameters, scoring='accuracy') 


    knn.fit(X_train, y_train) #error here
```